# Equivalent programmatic logger initialization for log4j to log4j2 migration

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to understand the programmatic side of log4j2, as I am migrating a lot of log4j 1.2 code. The following seems to be very different and more complicated to accomplish:

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.FATAL);
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(new PatternLayout(PatternLayout.TTCC_CONVERSION_PATTERN), "System.err"));
```

Can someone with plenty of log4j2 experience explain to me what the simple way to migrate the 2 above lines is?

EDIT: This is what I have so far:

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
config.getLoggerConfig(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME).setLevel(Level.FATAL);
PatternLayout patternLayout = PatternLayout.createLayout(PatternLayout.TTCC_CONVERSION_PATTERN, config, null, null, true, true, null, null);
Layout<? extends Serializable> layout = patternLayout;
ConsoleAppender consoleAppender = ConsoleAppender.createAppender(layout , null, "SYSTEM_ERR", "System.err", null, null);
consoleAppender.start();
config.addAppender(consoleAppender);
context.updateLoggers();
```

There is no way it is that complicated, right?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately creating programmatic configuration wasn't the main concern of Log4j2. You may check on their [AbstractConfiguration class sources](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/AbstractConfiguration.html) line 580 to see how default configuration is set programmatically internally.

Log4j2 library have good support for different types of configuration files (xml, json, properties, yaml) or you can build composite configuration out of several sources. Also it tracks configuration files and is capable of dynamic reloading.

I would remmend you evaluating features mentioned above to update configuration from code. E.g.

```
    final URL log4j = Resources.getResource("log4j2-test.xml");
    ConfigurationSource configurationSource = new ConfigurationSource(
            Resources.asByteSource(log4j).openStream(), log4j);

    LoggerContext context = LoggerContext.getContext(false);
    XmlConfiguration xmlConfiguration = new XmlConfiguration(context, configurationSource);

    context.start(xmlConfiguration);
```

Seem easier to manage than programmatic way with larger configurations.

Comment: I think this is the real answer. Even the documentation for programmatic examples is lacking on their site, so I think this has to be the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: I was trying to use 2.2. Programmatic configuration options in 2.10 are MUCH better.

Comment: Have you checked 2.10 release date? It was released a month *after* our conversation.

Comment: Yep, that is why I came back and responded, lol. Although the upgrades to the programmatic API were incremental.